# Timeline title is displaying partially in Area 51

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, area-51, timeline

In the Area 51, if the [question title is very lengthy](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/21783/timeline), when viewing from the timeline, some part of the title text is not displaying.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Area 51 - timeline title partial view]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the recent responsive design, the timeline title alignment issue for the lengthy title has been fixed.

Screenshot for reference:

> [image: Area 51 Discussion]